# How legacy transaction are handled after EIP1559 update?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, eip-1559

After the EIP1559 transaction gas is mainly divided into base gas price and priority gas fees. But as we know EIP1559 is backward compatible so how legacy transaction ( they just have gas price field) are handled after this update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559 proposal:

> Legacy Ethereum transactions will still work and be included in blocks, but they will not benefit directly from the new pricing system. This is due to the fact that upgrading from legacy transactions to new transactions results in the legacy transaction’s `gas_price` entirely being consumed either by the `base_fee_per_gas` and the `priority_fee_per_gas`.

Comment: what does this mean " but they will not benefit directly from the new pricing system"

Comment: @Proton I give an example of "How does EIP-1559 reduce overpayments?" in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103337/42