# Is it possible to re-route the “burned” gas from EIP-1559 and instead of burning it

Tags: solidity, blockchain, eip-1559

Is it possible to re-route the “burned” gas from EIP-1559 and instead of burning it, send it to a smart contract

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103274/how-does-eip-1559-make-ethereum-fees-better

Comment: No, its not related in my question im askting to transfer gas to the contract.

Comment: As @Seungbae answered, the burning is done by the protocol. The link I added has papers like https://timroughgarden.org/papers/eip1559.pdf that explain 1559 mechanics and burning.

Answer (score 1):

This seems impossible because 'burned' is done at the protocol level. If it must be done, the solution is to modify the protocol in the client code (hard fork).